# What to do if I lost my French visa?

Tags: visas, schengen-visas, long-stay-visas

I have been living and working in France for 2 months at a French university but recently on a trip to visit family in the UK I tragically and stupidly lost my passport and the (long-stay) visa contained within it. I have obtained a replacement passport but I'm not sure what to do about the visa.

I have been in France less than two months this year, so it seems to me I should be legally allowed to return for another 30 days whether I have my visa or not (since one can stay up to 90 days without a visa). Is this right? This is important because I have a seminar to give there, which would not be convenient to give remotely.

I would be extremely grateful for advice.

Comment: What is your citizenship? Exactly what kind of visa did you have?

Comment: @jcaron I am a british citizen and I have a long stay VLS "talent" visa.

Comment: As a British citizen you can most definitely enter France without a visa for up to 90 days out of 180, as long as you meet the conditions for a visitor (including not working, not getting paid…). For the rest, your question would be more appropriate on https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/

Comment: VLS-T or VLS-TS?

Comment: The other half of the question is: https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/26754/what-to-do-if-lost-french-visa

Comment: @NicolasFormichella I don't know. On the visa it just says "Pass. Talent, Chercheur, PT4 VLS"

Comment: Contact the issuing authority: you are not the only with such problem. You may just need a duplicate.